# "By the time you finish, she 'would' be asleep"

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verbs

"By the time you finish reading her a book, she **would** be asleep."

I understand that we can use "will" instead of "would", but I'm curious whether "would" can be used as stated above. I thought that it is still possible to use "would" if it is used in a way that implies uncertainty, as in "When I get there, she would be playing the piano." Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Would* implies uncertainty only in the conditional.

> If you [were to] read her a bedtime story, by the time you finished she would [probably] be asleep.

You can't use it following the present tense as in your examples.

Answer (score 2):

*"By the time you finish reading her a book, she would be asleep."*

In this sentence you should use 'will'. If there is doubt you would write, for example:

"**If** you finished reading her the book, she would be asleep."

or

"If you finish reading her the book, she **could** be asleep."